# Finding the domain of $\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$. (Am I correct?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I just had a test and was wondering if my answer to this domain question is correct.

> Find domain of $y=\dfrac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$

Of course the answer is $\{x \mid x\neq \pi + 2n\pi, n\text{ is an integer}\}$

But due to my obsession of double checking, I by accident changed the domain to  $\{x \mid x\neq -\pi + 2n\pi, n\text{ is an integer}\}$$\ldots$

Is this still correct? Cosine of $-\pi$ or $-180^\circ$ is *still* $-1$ which would make the denominator $0$, satisfying the domain I wrote the second time for my final answer. Of course the point of adding $2n\pi$ is to show that it has coterminal angles and such, and its best to add it to the domain of the angle in standard position.

Anyways, how likely would my changed answer get full marks, considering work was shown. :( rip why do I always do this!!!!!!

Comment: Check [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) to learn more about writing the equations.

Comment: Those are both the exact same set! If $x\in \{\pi + 2n\pi\}$ then $x = \pi + 2k$ for some integer $k$ and $x = -\pi + (2k+2)\pi \in \{-\pi +2n\pi\}$.  And vice versa.

Comment: 100% agree but don't you find it kind of odd to leave it like that?

Comment: To leave it like... what?

Comment: "how likely would my changed answer get full marks"  Depends on your teacher.  If you have an even *slightly* competent teacher you'd get full marks.  If you have an idiot of a teacher (and there are a *LOT* of those) who knows.

Answer (score 3):

If $$\pi+2n\pi=-\pi+2m\pi$$

$1+2n=2m-1\iff n=m-1$

So, both domains are actually identical

Comment: So my answer is correct? Are you sure because though it is identical, all domain calculators ive used shows the first answer with positve pi. The angle I put for the domain is not in standard position; the add or subtract 2pi has already been applied (angle in standard position - 2pi =pi - 2pi = -pi.) With these things said, are really sure my answer is correct?

Comment: It certainly is correct; whether it'll be *marked* correct is a different matter (sadly).

Comment: Why is that? Is it because the ambuguity of my answer to finding the domain is similar to that of not simplifying a fraction? For example, i put 2/4 instead of 1/2.

Comment: i really don't know why it would be marked wrong aside from presentation of the answer; as the angle is not in standard position. Any of you know does putting an answer like this matter? For example, instead of putting the part pi + 2npi in the domain, I put any one of the following: -3pi+ 2npi, -pi+2npi, 3pi +2npi and so on. Although all are correct, how likely would it still be marked correct based how your experience in math?

Comment: Domain calculators have to show *something*.  $\{39\pi + \frac {M+28}2\pi; M$ is four times an integer$\}$ is *also* correct.  The thing is the set $S = \{\pi+2n\pi; n\in \mathbb Z\}; T=\{-\pi+2n\pi; n\in \mathbb Z\}$ and $U=\{39\pi + \frac {M+28}2\pi; M$ is four times an integer$\}$ are each the *EXACT* same set!

Comment: @PatrickPichart Yes, you could write the domain as $\{x \mid x \neq 239581\pi + 2n\pi, n \in \Bbb Z\}$, or any other odd multiple of $\pi$. The reason why you'll see $\pi + 2n\pi$ in most "official" answers is just that $1$ is the natural choice for a simple odd number.

Comment: Obviously $\{39\pi + \frac {M+28}2\pi; M$ is four times an integer $\}$ is perverse.  But I think $\{k\pi| k$ is an odd integer$\}$ or $\{(2n-1)\pi; n\in \mathbb Z\}$ will be perfectly natural and common.  $\{-\pi + 2n\pi: n\in \mathbb Z\}$ isn't a "natural" way of *saying* it,  but $\{(2n-1)\pi: n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is.  Even though they are the exact same thing.

Comment: "The reason why you'll see π+2nπ in most "official" answers is just that 1 is the natural choice for a simple odd number."  I'd argue you are also likely to see $(2n +1)\pi$ and $(2n-1)\pi$.  But $-\pi + 2n\pi$ is not likely

Comment: @theophile yes that's exactly how i think of it. I think most official answers are the correct answers

Comment: Guys, just to clarify, is the "+ 2nπ" in the domain not written "± 2nπ" because of the "n" multiplied by 2π? To be clearer, n represents integers (...-2,-1,0,1,2,3....), so there is not need to write the "±" sign because if we chose a negative number for "n" it would make the + sign equivalent to the "±" sign? I'm asking this because I remember seeing this somewhere, where the ± sign was used for the domain

Comment: That's right, the $\pm$ would be redundant because the $n$ can already be positive or negative. Also, as @fleablood says, another very common way to write the set is $(2n+1)\pi$. The advantage to this way is that you can read it at a glance as "an odd multiple of $\pi$".

Comment: I don't think anyone is having issue with $+2n\pi$ but with the $-\pi + 2n\pi$.  Although one shouldn't as $-\pi + 2n\pi = \pi + 2(n-1)\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that your domain can be also written as the union of open intervals
$$](2k+1)\pi,(2k+3)\pi[$$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$ you can maybe be sure that you are correct (with the condition that your "$n$ is an integer" means rational integer, i. e. positive or negative or zero).